# ¿Cómo abrir Spyder desde WSL2/Ubuntu (sin Anaconda)?

Tags: ubuntu, spyder, wsl

Quiero abrir Spyder desde la terminal de Ubuntu en WSL. ¿Es posible? La terminal me arroja este error:

```
$ spyder
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.

Aborted
```

Sé que no se pueden abrir aplicaciones gráficas en WSL, pero ¿porque sí puedo abrir VS Code perfectamente con `code.`? Quiero hacer lo mismo con Spyder y no encuentro forma.
Gracias!

Comment: ¿Has probado reinstalar la aplicación o los plugins que se muestran en el stack de error?

Comment: Pude instalar y reinstalar xcb. El resto no. Los busqué de todas formas, con apt, con pip y no los encuentra.

Comment: Revisa que versión de Qt está instalada en tu máquina. Echa un vistazo a https://forum.qt.io/topic/75906/qt-5-8-installation-and-qt-creator-launch-issue/6

Comment: Bueno por lo que vi, es un error en la actualización de Spyder y se solucionará en las próximas versiones. Aún no lo probé.
Por sus respuestas, intuyo que al menos "es posible" abrirlo desde WSL, que era mi primer pregunta xD.
Gracias!